# Version Change issue in Android App

Tags: android

My developer made a mistake while creating the first version of the app. He didn't specifically include version number 1 in the first app. Now, we are going to update the app but the issue is, if we use 1.1 as android:versionCode, will this be recognized by Google play market as a update? My dev thinks it won't work properly since we didn't include version in the first app. My worst fear is Google might think its a new app altogether and duplicate it.

Any way out? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Google makes app listing based on the package name, not versions. Additionally, Google Play wouldn't have let you upload the app without a `versionCode`. You cannot have a `versionCode` like 1.1 because it must be an integer. The only rule with `versionCodes` is that the new update's code must be greater than the old one.

Also, `versionCodes` and `versionNames` are two different things. `versionCodes` are used by app stores to track updates, while `versionNames` are more common identifiers like 1.0.0 etc. `versionCodes` are limited to being integers, while `versionNames` can be alphanumeric. The below code snippet should give you an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) link for more details on versioning your app.

Comment: Thanks @Raghav Sood , So in short, if my developer includes android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1" in the app, it should work as a update?

Comment: The versionCode must be higher than the previous one. So if the previous one was one, then two will work. The versionName on the other hand can stay the same, or be changed to pretty much anything you want.

Comment: Thanks. am checking on the original version code. There is no way that he didn't include these details in the original app right?

Comment: To check the versionCode, go to the developer console and open up the app's page in the developer console. Over there, go to the Apk Files tab. The versionCode is given there.

Comment: Yes, I just did that. Version code: 1 and version name 1.0. So I think this is fine. I will just have to add versioncode = 2 and version name = 1.1 and it should be fine now.

Comment: Mainly the versionCode. versionNames can stay the same if you want.